# Converter JSON para CSV

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

Estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta que captura informações da API do github e salva em um arquivo `.json`.

Código:

```
const axios = require('axios')

const fs = require('fs')

const data = require('./data.json');

async function getResult(data) {

    for(a = 0; a < data.length; a++){

        data[a].atividades = {};

        for(b = 1; b <= 3; b++) {

            let lista = `Lista_${b}`;

            var res = await axios.get(`https://api.github.com/repos/org/repo/contents/turma-1/${data[a].REPO}/${lista}`)

            data[a].atividades[lista] = res.data.length - 1
        }
    }
    
    return data
}

getResult(data).then((res) => {
    console.log('casa', res);

    var array = []
    array.push(res)
    
    
    var arrayResultado = array
    var ArraySerealizado = JSON.stringify(arrayResultado)
    var caminhoDoArquivo = './resultado.json'
    fs.writeFileSync(caminhoDoArquivo, ArraySerealizado)
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Ao executar gera essa saída em json:

```
{
      "ID": 199,
      "NOME": "Davi xxxxx",
      "REPO": "xxxxx",
      "atividades": {
        "Lista_1": 0,
        "Lista_2": 0,
        "Lista_3": 0
      }
    },
```

Precisava converter esse 'resultado.json' para um arquivo CSV onde a estrutura ficasse assim;

coluna 1: nome
coluna 2: repo
coluna 3: lista_1
coluna 4: lista_2

E assim por diante...

Seria necessário mudar algo em meu código ou há uma forma de transformar o json em csv da forma em que tenho ele agora?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Fala Davi, beleza? Cara, tenta fazer o seguinto com o seu json:

```
var csv = json.map(function(row){
  return fields.map(function(fieldName){
    return JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)
  }).join(',')
})

csv.unshift(fields.join(','))
csv = csv.join('\r\n');
console.log(csv)
```

Comment: Oi João, obrigado pela resposta! Pode me explicar um pouco melhor essa resolução? Estou entrando no mundo de Javascript agora e confesso que não entendi exatamente como fazer :(